# Getting a var variable from document.getElementById('name') into a php variable

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)
>   [send javaScript variable to php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191124/send-javascript-variable-to-php-variable)

I have document.getElementById('name') field in a document that it's value is changed by script, when i do a post(to server) i want to get the current value of the document.getElementById('name') and set it in

in

```
$temp= document.getElementById('name');
?>
```

p.s. I know that the script code is don client side and the php i server side but i need this workaround so please help..

Comment: Many dups; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191124/send-javascript-variable-to-php-variable & see the "Related" sidebar

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't just post the name?

Comment: I cant find from where, the control is <input readonly= and initial value=0 and it allways takes 0

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option you have is to make an `AJAX` request with the values. With this you can send and assign the values to your `PHP variables`.

Else you can use `COOKIE` etc. to store the value temporarily and then use it on server side whenever a server side function is called next.

Ajax code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
    try {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(err1) {
      try {
      req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (err2) {
        try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (err3) {
          req = false;
        }
      }
    }
    return req;
    }



      var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();
       function sendValue() {
    var myurl = "session.php";  // to be present in the same folder
     var myurl1 = myurl;
    var value = document.getElementById('urDIV').value;
      myRand = parseInt(Math.random()*999999999999999);
      var modurl = myurl1+"?rand="+myRand+"url"+value ; // this will set the url to be sent

      http.open("GET", modurl, true);
      http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
      http.send(null);
    }


    function useHttpResponse() {
       if (http.readyState == 4) {
        if(http.status == 200) {
          var mytext = http.responseText;
          // I dont think u will like to do any thing with the response
          // Once you get the response, you are done.
            }
         }
         else {
             // don't do anything until any result is obtained
            }
        } 
</script>
```

HTML Part

```
// considering you are calling on a button call

<input type='button' onclick='sendValue();'>
```

Comment: Any referals to any examples how to do this ? Iam new to ajax!

Comment: Refer to this answer of mine. It contains the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615348/session-variables-sending-specific-variable-from-a-while-loop

Answer (score 0):

Make a new HTTP request that includes the data.

- You could generate a `<form>` and submit it.
- You could use Ajax
- You could set `location` to a new value
- etc